# Windows Scripting: If statement, comparison of two variables is not working

Tags: windows, script, batch-file

I have this part of the code which is running weird:

```
if !NoOfLines!==!trailer! (
   echo Count of records in DFUView interface verified ok. >> %LOG_DIR%\%SCRIPT_NAME%.log 
) else ( 
       echo Count of records in DFUView interface do not match trailer . !NoOfLines! !trailer!  Hence aborting. >> %LOG_DIR%\%SCRIPT_NAME%.log
       goto Error
)
```

Even though variables `NoOfLines` and `trailer` carry the same value, which I confirmed by printing with `echo`, the `If` command jumps to the `Else` part which is for the case when two variables are not equal.

Comment: what scriping langague is this exactly? it does not appear to be vbs or wscript/cscript. also never underestimate danger of whitespace. 'thing' != ' thing '.

Comment: This is windows batch scripting ...

Comment: I tried with !NoOfLines! == !trailer! instead of !NoOfLines!==!trailer!, it still doesnt work

Comment: (1) code snippet not complete: how variables are defined? (2) is delayed expansion enabled? (3)  In the `else` branch, echo `"!NoOfLines!" "!trailer!"`: are the same really?

Comment: @JosefZ That's my list of question too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows Batch scripting, variables must be surrounded by `%` not `!` when you're not using delayed expansion*.  This line of code works as expected:

```
if %NoOfLines%==%trailer% (
```

More information about the syntax of the `IF` statement can be obtained at the Command Prompt by typing `IF /?`.

*<sup>*Type `Setlocal /?` at the Command Prompt for more information about delayed variable expansion*</sup>

Comment: Incorrect answer, !var! is correct usage if delayed expansion is desired

Comment: Thanks for explaining the vote. Did the OP mention delayed expansion?

Comment: changing ! to % solved the problem. Code is working fine now. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @Tonny Based on the OP indicating Delayed Expansion is not being used, would you consider reversing your down vote?

Comment: @Twisty Done. It is clear from his later comments the original poster wasn't using delayed expansion.